# How to get a conversion factor in new system of unit

Tags: physics, units

There is some numerical relation $I = \frac{c}{8\pi} E^2$ between  the wave intensity $I$ and the electric field strength $E$  written in **CGS** (centimetre, gram, second) system of units, where $c$ is the speed of light

```
c = UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"], "Centimeters"/"Seconds"]
```

where the intensity $I$ is measured in `Quantity["Ergs"/"Centimeters"^2/"Seconds"]`
and the strength $E$ in electrostatic units (ESU) `Quantity["ESUsOfElectricField"]`.

The problem is, firstly, how do I ask Mathematica to obtain the conversion factor in a new system of unit where $I$ is measured in `Quantity["Watts"/"Centimeters"^2]` and $E$ in `Quantity["Volts"/"Centimeters"]`

In new system, we should have a relationship like $I = \frac{E^2}{377}$ with the conversion factor $1/377$. How do I get this factor?

Secondly, how can I prove that the dimension of the factor is `"Ohms"` i.e. $\frac{1}{377\,{\rm Ohms}}$. I could use

```
UnitConvert[Quantity["ESUsOfElectricField"], "Volts"/"Centimeters"]
```

> `149896229/500000 V/cm`

or

```
Solve[Quantity[x1, "ESUsOfElectricField"] ==  Quantity[x2, "Volts"/"Centimeters"], x2]
```

> `{{x2 -> (149896229 x1)/500000}}`

Comment: The appropriate formula for SI is $I=\frac{c\varepsilon_0}{2}E^2$. Recall that [Gaussian units treat electric charge differently from SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units#Unit_of_charge).

Comment: In your formula there  is no electric charge. It is electrical constant, Permittivity

Comment: You are using [esu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statcoulomb#General_incompatibility), no?

Comment: yes, for electrical field strength